# Gaussian fitted curve showing a tail that does not go back to base-level

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, lmfit

Based upon existing topics on Stackoverflow, I have managed to fit a Gaussian curve to my dataset. However, the fitted Gaussian shows one tail that does not go back to base-level (i.e., in the example below, the right tail suddenly stops at a higher y-value compared to the left tail). This surprises me, as per definition a Gaussian should show a perfectly symmetrical bell-shaped curve. How can I generate a Gaussian curve of which both tails are equally long (i.e., the tails stop at the same width measured from the plume center-line) and end at the same base-level (i.e., the same y-value)? The reason I would like to have this, is because in my data sometimes a second peak starts to arise while the first peak did not go back to base-level yet. I would like to separate these peaks by fitting a Gaussian that goes back to base-level, as theoretically each peak should go back to its base-level. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import numpy as np 
from lmfit import Model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

x = np.array([-20.0,-17.0,-14.0,-11.0,-8.0,-5.0,-2.0,1.0,4.0,7.0,10.0,13.0,16.0,19.0,22.0,25.0,28.0,31.0,34.0,37.0,40.0,43.0,46.0,49.0,52.0,55.0,58.0,61.0,64.0,67.0,70.0,73.0,76.0,79.0,82.0])

y = np.array([1.90269,1.93535,2.62402,3.08949,2.82409,3.07588,3.22015,3.18884,5.14053,10.5111,18.6118,28.6343,37.7625,46.3641,53.9163,60.7622,66.5765,71.0596,74.4948,77.7177,80.373,82.5833,83.9021,83.4652,79.0229,71.4679,61.93,52.113,43.8517,36.211,29.3815,23.8966,19.31,15.5209,12.4532])

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
   return (amp / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * wid)) * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2))

def line(x, slope, intercept):
   return slope*x + intercept

peak_index = find_peaks(y,height=27.6)[0][0]
mean = sum(x*y)/np.sum(y) #weighted arithmetic mean 

mod = Model(gaussian) + Model(line)
pars = mod.make_params(amp=max(y), cen=x[peak_index], 
wid=np.sqrt(sum((x-mean)**2 * y)/sum(y)), slope=0, intercept=1)
result = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
comps = result.eval_components()
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, comps['gaussian'], 'k--')
```

Edit: The following example hopefully illustrates why I am interested in this. I have a long data-set in which the signal of different sources are being measured. The data-set is processed such that it generates the arrays x_measured and y_measured that contain the measured values belonging to one source. My program automatically detects the plume that occurs within the measured values, and stores the values of this plume in arrays called x and y. To these x and y arrays, I perform a Gaussian fit.

However, sometimes the measured values show that 2 plumes are overlapping, hence there is no measured plume from and back to base-level. An example is given in the code below. My program for these measured values now gives a Gaussian fit whereby the right tail goes to around y=0, but the left tail of the Gaussian fit stops around y=4.5. I would like the left tail to also go back to around y=0. This is, because theoretically I know that each plume should start and go back to the same base-level, and I want to compute the plume-width of such a Gaussian plume. For the example below, the left tail does not go back to around y=0, hence I cannot determine the width of the plume. I would like to have a Gaussian-fit of which both tails go back to the same base-level of y=0, such that I can determine the width of the plume.

```
x_measured = np.arange(-20,245,3)
y_measured = np.array([38.7586,38.2323,37.2958,35.9924,34.4196,32.7123,31.0257,29.5169,28.3244,27.5502,27.2458,27.4078,27.9815,28.8728,29.9643,31.1313,32.2545,33.2276,33.9594,34.373,34.4041,34.0009,33.1267,31.7649,29.9247,27.6458,24.9992,22.0845,19.0215,15.9397,12.966,10.2127,7.76834,5.69046,4.00296,2.69719,1.73733,1.06907,0.629744,0.358021,0.201123,0.11878,0.0839719,0.0813392,0.104295,0.151634,0.224209,0.321912,0.441478,0.575581,0.713504,0.843351,0.954777,1.04109,1.09974,1.13118,1.13683,1.11758,1.07369,1.0059,0.917066,0.81321,0.703288,0.597775,0.506678,0.437843,0.396256,0.384633,0.405147,0.461496,0.560387,0.71144,0.925262,1.21022,1.56925,1.99788,2.48458,3.01314,3.56626,4.12898,4.69031,5.24283,5.78014,6.29365,6.77004,7.19071,7.53399,7.78019,7.91889])

x = np.arange(10,104,3)
y = np.array([22.4548,23.4302,25.3389,27.9929,30.486,32.0528,33.5527,35.1304,35.9941,36.8606,37.1889,37.723,36.4069,35.9751,33.8824,31.0909,27.4247,23.3213,18.8772,14.3363,11.1075,7.68792,4.54899,2.2057,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.179834,0])

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
 return (amp / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * wid)) * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2))

def line(x, slope, intercept):
 return slope*x + intercept

peak_index = find_peaks(y,height=27.6)[0][0]
mean = sum(x*y)/np.sum(y) #weighted arithmetic mean 

mod = Model(gaussian) + Model(line)
pars = mod.make_params(amp=max(y), cen=x[peak_index], 
wid=np.sqrt(sum((x-mean)**2 * y)/sum(y)), slope=0, intercept=1)
result = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
comps = result.eval_components()
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, comps['gaussian'], 'k--')
plt.plot(x_measured,y_measured)
```

Comment: It looks like it's just a question of choosing the plotting interval. Yes, the Gaussian is a symmetric function. But if the interval you choose to plot it is not centered around the Gaussian's mean, then the graph is not going to look symmetrical. Note that the graph **must** be truncated, because its infinite. Often we choose to truncate it far enough that the y-values are very close to 0. But we have to choose where to truncate. I don't know lmfit enough to tell you how to make that choice yourself, if you're unsatisfied by the automated choice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I expected that lmfit would truncate the left and right tail at the same height in order to generate a symmetrical bell-curve plot (as it should, per definition of a Gaussian curve). However, apparently it does not. But thanks for your advice, I will look into whether it is possible with lmfit to choose the point of truncation myself

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you expect a bimodal fit with the model you defined. Use two different Gaussian functions for your fit, then evaluate the fitted functions for a longer interval `x_fit` to see the curves returning to baseline:

```
import numpy as np 
from lmfit import Model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

x = np.array([-20.0,-17.0,-14.0,-11.0,-8.0,-5.0,-2.0,1.0,4.0,7.0,10.0,13.0,16.0,19.0,22.0,25.0,28.0,31.0,34.0,37.0,40.0,43.0,46.0,49.0,52.0,55.0,58.0,61.0,64.0,67.0,70.0,73.0,76.0,79.0,82.0])

y = np.array([1.90269,1.93535,2.62402,3.08949,2.82409,3.07588,3.22015,3.18884,5.14053,10.5111,18.6118,28.6343,37.7625,46.3641,53.9163,60.7622,66.5765,71.0596,74.4948,77.7177,80.373,82.5833,83.9021,83.4652,79.0229,71.4679,61.93,52.113,43.8517,36.211,29.3815,23.8966,19.31,15.5209,12.4532])

def gaussian1(x, amp1, cen1, wid1):
   return (amp1 / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * wid1)) * np.exp(-(x-cen1)**2 / (2*wid1**2))

def gaussian2(x, amp2, cen2, wid2):
   return (amp2 / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * wid2)) * np.exp(-(x-cen2)**2 / (2*wid2**2))

#peak_index = find_peaks(y,height=27.6)[0][0]
#mean = sum(x*y)/np.sum(y) #weighted arithmetic mean 

mod = Model(gaussian1) + Model(gaussian2)
#I just filled in some start values, the details of educated guesses can be filled in later by you
pars = mod.make_params(amp1=30, amp2=40, cen1=20, cen2=40, wid1=2, wid2=2)
result = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(result.params)
x_fit=np.linspace(-30, 120, 500)
comps_elem = result.eval_components(x=x_fit)
comps_comb = result.eval(x=x_fit)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x_fit, comps_comb, 'k')
plt.plot(x_fit, comps_elem['gaussian1'], 'k-.')
plt.plot(x_fit, comps_elem['gaussian2'], 'k--')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

The corresponding `scipy.curve_fit` function would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [-20.0,-17.0,-14.0,-11.0,-8.0,-5.0,-2.0,1.0,4.0,7.0,10.0,13.0,16.0,19.0,22.0,25.0,28.0,31.0,34.0,37.0,40.0,43.0,46.0,49.0,52.0,55.0,58.0,61.0,64.0,67.0,70.0,73.0,76.0,79.0,82.0]

y = [1.90269,1.93535,2.62402,3.08949,2.82409,3.07588,3.22015,3.18884,5.14053,10.5111,18.6118,28.6343,37.7625,46.3641,53.9163,60.7622,66.5765,71.0596,74.4948,77.7177,80.373,82.5833,83.9021,83.4652,79.0229,71.4679,61.93,52.113,43.8517,36.211,29.3815,23.8966,19.31,15.5209,12.4532]

def gauss(x, mu, sigma, A):
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2) 

def bimodal(x, mu1, sigma1, A1, mu2, sigma2, A2):
    return gauss(x, mu1, sigma1, A1) + gauss(x, mu2, sigma2, A2)

expected = (20, 2, 30, 40, 2, 40)
params, cov = curve_fit(bimodal, x, y, expected)
sigma=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
x_fit = np.linspace(-20, 120, 500)
plt.plot(x_fit, bimodal(x_fit, *params), color='red', lw=3, label='model')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[:3]), color='red', lw=1, ls="--", label='distribution 1')
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss(x_fit, *params[3:]), color='red', lw=1, ls=":", label='distribution 2')
plt.scatter(x, y, marker="X", color="black", label="original data")
plt.legend()
print(pd.DataFrame(data={'params': params, 'sigma': sigma}, index=bimodal.__code__.co_varnames[1:]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. With respect to your first phrase; I have just editted my original post. Hopefully, this will clarify why I am interested that both tails of the Gaussian fit go back to the same base-level (in this case, y =0)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot follow your logic. You want to enforce a Gaussian fit although the signal obviously is not just one Gaussian curve, and you want the fit forced to zero on the right side although the curve form implies that it is just the lack of follow-up data points why the fitted curve doesn't return to baseline?  If you do this, you will seriously distort your amplitude/center evaluation. If you have a suspected overlay of two Gaussians, don't separate them arbitrarily but fit the entire set with the bimodal Gaussian function as shown. Or maybe I simply do not understand the problem.